# Locayta indexer update

Tags: full-text-search

I am using Locayta for Full Text Search in one of my projects, and the entity I need to search has text content and tags, looking at the LocNotes code, looks like every time any aspect of the entity changes, I need to update it in Locayta Indexer, so if the text content is 100KB and I only modified the tags, it still does re-index the 100KB text content even it is not changed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of Locayta's developers; your assumption there is correct. Locayta Search treats each document as a single entity, so at the moment the full document has to be re-sent if any aspect of it has been updated.

In the future, if there's enough demand for it, we may add the ability to update the boolean values stored for the document separately, but there would probably be a lot of provisos around such an update due to how Locayta Search stores various aspects of each document separately. The most reliable way to update a document will always be to send the entire document data each time.